# use jenkins to build from specific git tag instead of building the whole branch

Tags: git, jenkins

At the moment, I have jenkins build, which make clean install on master branch. When we deliver a hotfix, we just deliver the commits starting form a defined tag and not the whole branch.

How to configure jenkins to make clean install on the branch starting from a specific tag on the branch?

Answer (score 0):

In jenkins job configuration, create a step on build section to exec a shell command (assuming you are using linux) then write the follow command on your workspace folder

```
git checkout tags/${YOUR_TAG_NAME}
```

Or you can config like [here](http://git%20--work-tree=/opt/joomlaIC/%20checkout%20tags/$%7BSELECT_TAG%7D)